# stop loading data after 15 min c#

Tags: c#

I am writing an website where I get some data from the database. When starting the website on my computer I get the data for 15 min. After these 15 min the files don't load anymore.

[image]

When I restart the backend (Visual Studio C#) then it happens the same.

Controller from the file:

```
[UnitOfWorkActionFilter]
[RoutePrefix("categories")]
public class CategoriesController : ApiController {
    private ICategoriesProcessor _categoriesProcessor;
    private IPagedDataRequestFactory _pagedDataRequestFactory;
    public CategoriesController(ICategoriesProcessor categoriesProcessor, IPagedDataRequestFactory pagedDataRequestFactory) {
        _pagedDataRequestFactory = pagedDataRequestFactory;
        _categoriesProcessor = categoriesProcessor;
    }

    [Route()]
    [HttpGet]
    public PagedResponse<Category> GetCategories(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage) {
        var request = _pagedDataRequestFactory.Create(requestMessage.RequestUri);
        return _categoriesProcessor.GetCategories(request);
    }
}
```

here is the code from the UnitWorkActionFilterAttribute

```
 public class UnitOfWorkActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public virtual IActionTransactionHelper ActionTransactionHelper { get { return WebContainerManager.Get<IActionTransactionHelper>(); } }
    public override bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        ActionTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
        ActionTransactionHelper.EndTransaction(actionExecutedContext);
        ActionTransactionHelper.CloseSession();
    }
}
```

I found out that the problem is, that the Session opens but not close but I don't know how to fix it.

Does someone has an idea why it's not working?

Comment: Please show you code in client how to get data, and what the code in `[UnitOfWorkActionFilter]` , show code in that attribute.....
Why your attribute `[Route()]` its empty navigation Route, you must declare the route like this [`Route("GetCategories")]` or any thing name route you want...
Trying to Debug / Breakpoint in your code, and try access your API from [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: it plays no role if I write it like my solution or your solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you try access from Fiddler ??? what the client you used to call your API...
see what the fiddler got message, and if you call the API, that is call that Method API or not...need detail information, this error have come to method or just in client stuff...